# How is Esri online course data spatially referenced without xy coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, xy

I have completed ESRI's online course, Mapping Racial Disparities in Breast Cancer Mortality Rates Using ArcGIS Pro, which analyzed the disparities between black and white women by county. Here is their data:
[Breast Cancer Mortality Rate by Race 2018](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?useExisting=1&layers=b69f6598492442e38c98fda12b7fd366)

I want to continue the research using data of other races of women. I have found the [data](https://statecancerprofiles.cancer.gov/deathrates/index.php?stateFIPS=39&areatype=county&cancer=055&race=00&sex=2&age=001&year=0&type=death&sortVariableName=rate&sortOrder=default#results) for the other races, but cannot project it because there are no long/lat coordinates in the table. ESRI's data table for black and white women also has no long/lat coordinates, but it is spatially referenced. Every county in the data appears on the map where it should. How did they spatially reference their data? I would like to know so I can continue the research for the other races.

Comment: It's spatially referenced as it is a [polygon](https://support.esri.com/en-us/gis-dictionary/polygon) [feature class](https://support.esri.com/en-us/gis-dictionary/feature-class).  I presume they made a copy of the county boundaries and added the mortality data to the attribute table.  You could do the same by joining your data to county boundaries.

Comment: Correct - the tiger county layer has a field called Countyns, which corresponds to CountyGNIS Code in the cancer layer. Thank you.